# AWS IoT action to serverless OpenSearch

Tags: amazon-opensearch

In AWS we have a `Serverless OpenSearch`.

In AWS IoT we're trying to add a rule that connects to Serverless OpenSearch through an action.

[image]

The problem is that I need to specify a domain name, but it seems to me that Serverless OpenSearch doesn't get any "domain".

So do you know if it is possible to set up an action that connects to OpenSearch serverless? What is the domain name (if any) of OpenSearch serverless?